# Best way to find a string in a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, string

If I have an array that contains some strings like so

```
$roleNames = ['sales_agent', 'admin'];
```

And I want to check if that array contains the string 'sales_agent', what would be the best way to go about this with PHP?

Ideally I would like to have the check return a boolean value.

Comment: [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) ? `if(in_array("sales_agent",$roleNames)) { echo "Hello world!" }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest Way

```
$word='admin';
$array = array('sales_agent', 'admin');

if (in_array($word, $array)) {
    echo "admin is in array";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use PHP's built-in [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function.

Example:

```
<?php
$os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux");
if (in_array("Irix", $os)) {
    echo "Got Irix";
}
if (in_array("mac", $os)) {
    echo "Got mac";
}
?>
```